# Formula of snubber capacitor capacitance for SCR dV/dt protection

Tags: capacitor, snubber, scr

I have a formula here for finding the suitable value of shunt capacitance to be put on an SCR snubber:

$$ C=\frac{1}{2L}\left(\frac{0.546 V}{\frac{dV}{dt}} \right)^2 $$

L is the snubber inductor, V is the DC supply voltage and \$\frac{dV}{dt}\$ the maximum allowable surge voltage. My question is about the derivation of the said equation—if it is a correct one. The formula looks bizarre to me when considering the equation for getting the right inductor, \$V = L\frac{di}{dt}\$, which is more straightforward. Moreover, I'm puzzled why choosing the capacitor value would depend on the series snubber inductor.

Comment: L is the load inductance

Comment: Based on my experience I think it's the snubber inductor.

Comment: There is no snubber inductor, just RC snubber. The snubber circuit is connected in parallel with SCR.

Comment: Yes, and an inductor would be connected in series to protect the SCR from di/dt. So essentially it is also in series with and becomes part of the load, as you said it is load inductance.

Comment: @DorkOrc But even if what you said were true (and I've never heard of a snubber inductor before), this isn't that scenario. Just as you already said, the equation is using dV/dT, not dI/dT. The L here is the load inductance.

Comment: Can only guess without a schematic -- voting to close.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question.

The inductor stores energy in the current: 0.5 * L * I^2

The snubber capacitor needs to store that same amount of energy, as voltage across the capacitor: 0.5 * C * V^2

Equate the two energy equations, and have fun.